# Closing Java Application immediately from Windows Service

Tags: java

I have a Windows Service, which "controls" a java-based application. In case of terminating the windows service, the java application should close as fast as possible. This killing procedure works, but not in a fast time.

So, for me, there are multiple possibilities: Either the java-app does not recognize directly this "termination command" or any kind of corba-interface, which is used inside of the java-app blocks the termination procedure for 30-60 seconds.

Are there any advices, of how to kill such a java based application at the moment, when terminating the windows service (the current state of the interfaces do not matter, they can be killed as well)?

Comment: how do you wrap java application as windows service?

Comment: We have some kind of wrapping service, which is able to start any kind of application, e.g. bat-files, dotnet or java-bnased applications. With any kind of other application types a service is closed immediately, but the java ones are very lazy. So dont know, if it is a general java problem or some kind of internal "blocking interface"-problem or anything like this.